Is there a more compact way to print factor levels in a matrix than to use apply?
I have a matrix which would be a matrix of factors if R supported them. I want to print the matrix with the factor names, rather than integers, for readability. Using indexing loses the matrix structure. Is there a tidier workaround than the one I have below?
care_types = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L), dim = c(10L, 6L))

care_type_names = c('M', 'F', 'O', 'I', 'H', 'C')


# This loses the dimensions
care_type_names[care_types]

# This works but is clunky
apply(care_types, 1:2, function(v) {return(care_type_names[[v]])})

# This doesn't work and I don't follow why
apply(care_types, 1:2, ~care_type_names[[.x]])


apply(care_types, 1:2, \(x) care_type_names[[x]])?

Looks like apply(care_types, 2, \(x) care_type_names[x]) also works.

@Mohan yes apply(care_types, 2, ...) works and saves a lot of time compared to apply(care_types, 1:2, ...). You can check the benchmark part in my answer!

Though care_type_names[care_types] loses the dimensions, you can reshape it into an array() with the original dimensions.
array(care_type_names[care_types], dim(care_types))

#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#  [1,] "M"  "H"  "M"  "F"  "O"  "I" 
#  [2,] "M"  "H"  "M"  "M"  "C"  "H" 
#  [3,] "M"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "M"  "O" 
#  [4,] "M"  "C"  "M"  "H"  "H"  "M" 
#  [5,] "M"  "H"  "F"  "F"  "C"  "F" 
#  [6,] "M"  "I"  "M"  "M"  "H"  "F" 
#  [7,] "M"  "M"  "M"  "H"  "H"  "M" 
#  [8,] "M"  "C"  "C"  "F"  "M"  "O" 
#  [9,] "M"  "I"  "H"  "O"  "H"  "H" 
# [10,] "M"  "I"  "M"  "M"  "C"  "H"


Benchmark on a larger matrix
array() slightly outperforms replace() and apply() when the matrix is large. (1000x1000 in this case)
Update!
The `dim<-`() method proposed by @ThomasIsCoding further improves the performance.
care_types <- matrix(sample(1:26, 1e6, replace = TRUE), nrow = 1e3, ncol = 1e3)
care_type_names <- LETTERS

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  tic = `dim<-`(care_type_names[care_types], dim(care_types)),
  darren = array(care_type_names[care_types], dim(care_types)),
  thelatemail_1 = replace(care_types, , care_type_names[care_types]),
  thelatemail_2 = `[<-`(care_types, , care_type_names[care_types]),
  Mohan = apply(care_types, 2, \(x) care_type_names[x]),
  Bernhard = apply(care_types, 1:2, \(x) care_type_names[[x]]),
  times = 100L,
  check = "identical",
  unit = "relative"
)

# Unit: relative
#           expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
#            tic   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000  1.0000000   100  a 
#         darren   1.840252   1.768748   1.270138   1.785627   1.757518  0.2196492   100  a 
#  thelatemail_1   3.226985   3.226587   2.469337   3.169915   3.138248  1.3020976   100  a 
#  thelatemail_2   3.090107   3.088408   2.252608   3.032059   4.644815  0.3800733   100  a 
#          Mohan   3.729082   3.745017   2.834293   3.737331   5.164634  1.0882580   100  a 
#       Bernhard 268.241097 299.505030 180.258010 287.793907 283.245930 15.8452711   100  b


good array approach plus a benchmark, +1! I think array is a nice start point. If you want to boost the speed, you can try dim<- directly, which is shorter and seems faster. I guess array has some overhead when being initialized.

Still do your indexing directly, but replace the original structure:
replace(care_types, , care_type_names[care_types])

This is essentially the same as overwriting the original structure using [<-
out <- care_types
out[] <- care_type_names[care_types]
out

Both giving:
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
## [1,] "M"  "H"  "M"  "F"  "O"  "I" 
## [2,] "M"  "H"  "M"  "M"  "C"  "H" 
## [3,] "M"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "M"  "O" 
## [4,] "M"  "C"  "M"  "H"  "H"  "M" 
## [5,] "M"  "H"  "F"  "F"  "C"  "F" 
## [6,] "M"  "I"  "M"  "M"  "H"  "F" 
## [7,] "M"  "M"  "M"  "H"  "H"  "M" 
## [8,] "M"  "C"  "C"  "F"  "M"  "O" 
## [9,] "M"  "I"  "H"  "O"  "H"  "H" 
##[10,] "M"  "I"  "M"  "M"  "C"  "H" 


A one step variant might be \[<-`(care_types, care_type_names[care_types])`

You can simply use `dim<-`
care_types <- matrix(sample(1:26, 1e6, replace = TRUE), nrow = 1e3, ncol = 1e3)
care_type_names <- LETTERS

microbenchmark(
  darren = array(care_type_names[care_types], dim(care_types)),
  tic = `dim<-`(care_type_names[care_types], dim(care_types)),
  check = "identical",
  unit = "relative"
)

which gives
Unit: relative
   expr      min       lq    mean   median       uq      max neval
 darren 2.402979 1.886056 1.78914 1.891474 1.822222 1.223973   100
    tic 1.000000 1.000000 1.00000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100


You could write an anonymous function with \(x) as in
apply(care_types, 1:2, \(x) care_type_names[[x]])

which returns
 [1,] "M"  "H"  "M"  "F"  "O"  "I" 
 [2,] "M"  "H"  "M"  "M"  "C"  "H" 
 [3,] "M"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "M"  "O" 
 [4,] "M"  "C"  "M"  "H"  "H"  "M" 
 [5,] "M"  "H"  "F"  "F"  "C"  "F" 
 [6,] "M"  "I"  "M"  "M"  "H"  "F" 
 [7,] "M"  "M"  "M"  "H"  "H"  "M" 
 [8,] "M"  "C"  "C"  "F"  "M"  "O" 
 [9,] "M"  "I"  "H"  "O"  "H"  "H" 
[10,] "M"  "I"  "M"  "M"  "C"  "H" 

The result is a matrix of type character:
> apply(care_types, 1:2, \(x) care_type_names[[x]]) |> typeof()
[1] "character"

However, the tidiest way to handle that might be writing your own print function for your kind of integer matrix that is supposed to be printed like a matrix of factors. It might start as simple as the following one or grow to your liking:
care_types = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                         6L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 
                         1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 
                         5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L), dim = c(10L, 
                                                                                              6L))
care_type_names = c('M', 'F', 'O', 'I', 'H', 'C')


mprint <- function(m, n = c('M', 'F', 'O', 'I', 'H', 'C')){
  for(row in 1:nrow(m)){
    cat("  | ")
    for(column in 1:ncol(m)){
      cat("  ")
      cat(n[m[row, column]])
    }
    cat("  |\n")
  }
}

mprint(care_types)
#>   |   M  H  M  F  O  I  |
#>   |   M  H  M  M  C  H  |
#>   |   M  H  H  H  M  O  |
#>   |   M  C  M  H  H  M  |
#>   |   M  H  F  F  C  F  |
#>   |   M  I  M  M  H  F  |
#>   |   M  M  M  H  H  M  |
#>   |   M  C  C  F  M  O  |
#>   |   M  I  H  O  H  H  |
#>   |   M  I  M  M  C  H  |

Created on 2024-08-18 with reprex v2.1.1
